# Defining (embedding) Javascript

Tags: javascript, executable

I would like to collect all possible ways with which JavaScript can be defined in the web page for execution.

So far I know the basic part:

- script tag
- external script
- element attributes that start with "on"
- inside some tag: WIDTH="&{barWidth};%" ALIGN="LEFT"
- CSS IE: style="left:expression(document.body.clientWidth/2-oDiv.offsetWidth/2);"
- DHTML behavior in IE
- in links: href="javascript:alert('Hi')"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More fugly things:

[CSS expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE — allows defining CSS properties as JavaScript expressions, which are evaluated on every possible DOM-event (on every mouse move, scroll step and so on).

[DHTML Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE — can bind `.htc`-files with JScript to HTML elements through CSS.

[XBL bindings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference), Mozilla's invention, can be [defined via CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/Binding_Attachment_and_Detachment#Attachment_using_CSS) as well.

Comment: So this CSS expressions are only characteristic for IE. Other browser will encounter it as a error?

Comment: Other browsers just ignore unknown/erroneous CSS values.

Answer (score 2):

In links, `<a href="javascript:alert('Hi')">`

Comment: Hmm, one or two year ago this code (javascript in `href` tag of anchor `a`) does not work in Opera. `href` attribute is not valid  place for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only one left is in the `href` attribute of <strike>anchors</strike> links like:

`<a href="javascript:alert('hello, world!');">Say Hello</a>`

This is how [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) work.

This document describes all ways of embedding: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch12_02.htm

Comment: If it has an *href* attribute it is a link. It might also be an anchor if it has a *name* attribute, but the above shows only a link.

Comment: So this syntax is just binded to the href attribute or browsers will execute it anywhere?

Comment: @bellpeace it is binded to the href

Comment: Just for the record, the present tesnse of "bind" is "bound", not "binded".

Comment: Sorry, I am not from country where English is dominant language, so sometimes I miss tense.